# What is the word could be used instead of "have"?

Tags: verbs, synonyms

What does the verb "have" mean in the following sentences? What does each use imply or what is the synonym of "have" in each instance?

> - Have mercy on me.
> - Have fun.
> - Let's have a legendary celebration for
>   you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - ***Show*** mercy towards me.
> - ***Enjoy*** yourself.
> - Let's ***organise*** a legendary celebration for you.

Comment: Thanks. This is completely what I want. So, is there a special reason to use "have"?

Comment: These are simply idiomatic phrases commonly used. I am sure there is a reason for each one and a way in which they came into being.